# Attribute evaluator with unbalanced dataset in Weka

Tags: machine-learning, attributes, random-forest, weka

I have a unbalanced dataset. So I got very poor performance when using classifier. It is a binary class problem and I am using `Random forest` as a classifier. The ratio of `True negative` with `True positive` is 7:1. So I tried to fix the problem and used `Subset Evaluator` with `Random Forest` and used `BestFirst search` to find out important attributes. Then I used only the important attributes in my dataset and the class attribute and discarded all other attribute. Then I again performed `Random Forest` on the dataset. Now it gives even more poor performance. The `True negative` and `true positive` ration is like 12:1. I am using Weka for the entire process.

I would like to know does attribute evaluator work for unbalanced dataset?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a subset of attributes highly correlates with the majority class label, then it is not surprising that this will acerbate the imbalance. After all, you are removing the attributes that correlate with the minority class label(s).

Comment: So, Subset Evaluator is not useful for highly imbalanced data?